# jquery insert table rows between other table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two tables:

```
<table width="200" id="table1" border=1 style="float:left;">
<tr><th>Subject</th><th>Hour</th></tr>
<tr class="head"><td colspan=2>MONDAY</td></tr>
<tr><td>English</td><td>3pm</td></tr>
<tr><td>Spanish</td><td>4pm</td></tr>
<tr class="head"><td colspan=2>TUESDAY</td></tr>
<tr><td>Italian</td><td>1pm</td></tr>
<tr><td>French</td><td>2pm</td></tr>
<tr class="head"><td colspan=2>WEDNESDAY</td></tr>
<tr><td>Japanese</td><td>10pm</td></tr>
</table>
<table width="200" id="table2" border=1 style="float:left;">
<tr><th>Users</th></tr>
<tr class="second"><td>User1</td></tr>
<tr class="second"><td>User2</td></tr>
<tr class="second"><td>User3</td></tr>
<tr class="second"><td>User4</td></tr>
<tr class="second"><td>User5</td></tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

What i want to achieve is, for every head class in table 1 I want to insert blank table row so users in table 2 will match the correct subjects (not day names), so it will be `User1` is in same line with `English`, `User1` -> `Spanish` ... and so on.

Note:
If you ask why those tables looks like this, it's because they are loaded dynamically from another pages and I can only set for example some id attributes to td's, tr's or tables etc. with jquery/javascript. Example ready to paset into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQ9TQ/)

Edit:
I want to insert blank row in table two so they both look the same. Here's link with results i want to achieve [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/4pdCq/)

Comment: You want to insert the blank row in table1 or table2? That isn't clear from your question.

Comment: Looks like you posted a blank jsFiddle!

Comment: Can you show what you want the result to look like? The questions is confusing.

Comment: my mistake, update in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rcSh9/4/)**

I get it, you have two tables next to each other and need gaps in the right hand one to clear the "head" rows

```
// edited to cope with hidden trs in table 1
var emptytr=$('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>');
$('#table1 tr:visible').each(function(i){
    if ($(this).hasClass('head')){ 
        emptytr.clone().insertAfter('#table2 tr:eq('+(i-1)+')');
    }
});​
```

This is not a good way to display the tabular results as they could easily become misaligned. The correct method would be to conjoin the two, preferably before they exist on a browser. However, you've said you can't do this on the browser because they load dynamically but personally I would still persist in being able to identify which row each item of data belongs to and make the whole thing one table.

Comment: this is working great, but now I realised that I have some table rows in table one with css display:none; How can I ommit them in your loop, because they destroy whole view. [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rcSh9/7/)

Comment: grrrrr. edited. Oh wait, you don't mean that...

Comment: no, but don't be angry..

Comment: yes, now it's working with hidden tr's ... many thanks !!!